# Is it safe to include the IV at the end of a hash?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, initialisation-vector

I have a PHP function I have written that uses a 64 bit binary string and a random initialization vector to encode data using the following basic principal:

```
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data_to_encrypt, AES_256_CTR, $64bit_binary_string, 0, $iv);
```

Then in order for me to decrypt the message I have to know the IV so I tie this to the new hash with a colon separator:

```
$encrypted = $encrypted . ':' . $iv;
```

Finally, I base64 encode the entire thing for another purpose

I have read that the IV does not need to be secret as long as it is random.  If this is true then am I correct in assuming that it is safe to be included at the end of the hash like this? Obviously, base64 is easy to reverse so once that has been done, I assume it would be easy for anyone to guess what the IV is. The problem would be decoding the 64bit string.

Comment: Encryption is not hashing and a ciphertext is not a hash. Yes, simply adding the IV to the ciphertext is safe. Note however the ciphertext is and the IV should be random binary data that can easily contain the byte value for ':' so you must not parse the result using the colon, you must parse it by knowing the correct length of the IV and taking that length then removing the colon. If by '64-bit string' you mean 8 _bytes_, that is not a very good key for AES-128 and using AES-256 is totally wasted, while if you mean 64 characters each '0' or '1' that is super weak.

Comment: Alternatively and more flexibly you can base64 each and concat _those_ with colon which allows parsing because a base64 encoding never includes a colon.

Comment: Could you describe your use case a bit here? What are you trying to accomplish? There seems to be some confusion regardin encoding/encrypting/hashing.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thank you for the clarification on the terminology the IV length check makes sense.  My IV is randomly generated and my key looks like the following (obviously not the real key)

$key = hex2bin('cj90d85t6c1234895a3369be123p061b32q653ad6af381f0d36abde3a3215987');

Comment: @Anders I am using this to store passwords and also using it to load pages dynamically ie  index.php?P=alkjearhiuearndlkjhgoiaie may go to the about us page.  But the primary use of this is to encrypt sensitive information into the database

Comment: Please don't store passwords (even encrypted) in your database if not absolutely necessary. Take a look at the http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php function for passwords.

Comment: @VaaChar how would I have them log in if I don't store the password?

Comment: You store the hash that is generated by password_hash() in your database and in your login function you validate the entered password against your stored hashes for the user with the function password_verify(). http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IV is not secret so it doesn't matter how you store it. It's perfectly find to append it to a hash.